# Clangs SanitizerCoverage with shared libraries

Tags: clang++, sanitizer

I am having trouble in using the `sancov`tool of clang with shared libraries.
While it works like [documented](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/SanitizerCoverage.html) for a simple binary I am not able to get it to work with shared libraries.

Whenever I use a shared library from my program I do get a `*.sancov` file for it but when I try to get a report from `sancov` I receive the following error message:

> Ignoring libMyLib.so and its coverage because  __sanitizer_cov* functions were not found.

It seems that the problem stems from the fact the the sanitizer functions are unresolved in my shared library. But I am not sure though.

> nm libMyLib.so | grep saniti
>   U __sanitizer_cov
>   U __sanitizer_cov_module_init
>   U __sanitizer_cov_with_check

Can someone give me hint what I am doing wrong?